# How can I state a variable in C++ based on an Java program variable?

Tags: java, c++

Firstly I would like to excuse my question for being very strange, but I really don't know how to directly ask the thing I want, as so I would like to give an example:

I have an C++ program in which I have a variable, lets say 'x', and in my java application I have also an 'x', which indicate my character position on the map. I would like to 'bind' the variable from my java game into the variable of my C++ program, as so I can make conditions in my C++ Program using the value that is being held on my Java game.

I have used an memory manager program, and I was able to identify the memory address of this variable, I can make my C++ variable to hold the vale of that memory address's value, BUT if I do this way I would end up needing to locate and change the address each and every time I close the applications, because the memory would have changed place of allocation.

Considering these statements above how may I be able to 'bind' an certain value on my Java Application into my C++ Program?

BTW this seem pretty much like a game 'bot' but its about measure of security which I want to be implemented.

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT: I was thinking about the issue and I see that doing it in C++ being the primary target in java, might get little tricky, so i'm adding the possibility to implement it in Java if it would help.

Comment: just don't do it. Either you interface your game correctly, perhaps loading the native c++ dll from your java game, or you start another process and communicate between the two

Comment: How not? There is plenty of BOTs out there which implements the same thing! lets say, an RPG Bot that will walk across the map and kill the monsters, this BOT program would need to have access to the game X and Y positions. I wanted to make it without the communication between the two of them, so I can protect that from happening.

Comment: *I am no expert on this sort of interface.* I guess that getter and setter functions are created for accessing the variables for bots. e.g. `getX()` and `setX()` .

Comment: Ok but how may I use an program function when all I have is the executable? (in the case of a BOT)

Comment: Low-level binary manipulation. Which is really hard.

Comment: But using this I would be editing the game, wouldn't I? I wanted to make it without changing the sources or the executable.

Comment: a lot of aim hacks for video games use dll injection. If you inject a library into a running process, then you're running in the same address space as the process, so the address of X won't change unless you edit the game.

Comment: If you have the C++ source, you could use JNI.

Comment: @JoeRunde Omg that sounds amazing! can you give me more information about that? KevinMangold: I'll look into that

Comment: http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/01/windows-dll-injection-basics.html Here's an explanation of how it works with some example code.

Comment: @JoeRunde Nice! Thanks for that, as you said before, after the injection, I can read the memory which the DLL process is in, and by that I can get like REAL position of the variable I want? even after I restart the APP or my PC? like lets say 1024 bytes away in memory?

Comment: Yeah, assuming there's some stack variable pointing to it that isn't dynamically allocated. Once you find the position of the variable or a pointer to it relative to the start of the program, then you'll have it every time the app starts. Google around some, I found this http://www.blizzhackers.cc/viewtopic.php?t=462933